# Plot quarterly and annual data on same graph in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I need to plot two time series on the same graph. One series has *annual* observations, while the other series has *quarterly* observations. Is there straightforward way to do this?

The only solution I have come up with is to expand the annual data by repeating each year's observation four times, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this within gnuplot instead of by editing my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarterly plots in gnuplot are not supported. ([check this link)](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00066000000000000000).
Maybe you can restructure your data to plot a time series with each point representing a year and another time series where each points represents a month?

I fiddled a little around with two time series (one containing yearly the other containing quarterly data) but could not find a satisfying solution. I am looking forward to other responses.